# Regex to capture variables with multiple values from columns

Tags: regex, string, text, extract, ocr

I need to capture both of these values with separate workflow elements. (3rd line value directly below "Soldto:" and the same with "Shipto:". The text is arranged in columns on the page, so treating it as a simple pattern does not work. Please advise.

[image: ShiptoandSoldto]

The image is realistic because of the fact that the text is generated by scanning and OCR'ing TIF images, but here is some text that I have reproduced for testing (more condensed than it is on the page)

```
Soldto:                                 Shipto:                                 Billto:                                 
00011222                                00017872                                10221060                                
COSTCO CO INC. - GLOBAL EDI             COSTCO LANGLEY DEPOT                    COSTCO CO/LANGLEY
```

To avoid all the HTML formatting necessary to get these columns to line up, I have linked the sample text as a [.txt file.](http://secure.copiersnw.com/main.html?download&weblink=c82be5b4e3081f7a62213465a0a62579&realfilename=samplecolumns.txt)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: By the way, the interface is Laserfiche Workflow Pattern Matching. Uses regex to ID Soldto: or Shipto: on the page, and then I need help going to the third line and picking up about 35 characters and spaces and punctuation.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and put the actual **text** inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found out a couple of things about Laserfiche.
1. It does not use the \R and \K commands, so the PHP code won't work.
2. It does not keep the OCR results in columns, so the parsing through the columns, while super cool, is not necessary.

Here is some of the text:
BRANDS: PRODUCTION Time: 10:03:09
Sotdto:
00011222
COSTCO CO INC. - GLOBAL EDI
WA,
Shipto:
00010377
COSTCO/TRACY #179
25862 S SCHULTE
TRACY, CA, 95376

Here are the Regular Expressions that did the job:
a. Soldto: `So[lit1I|]dto:(?:\s+\d+\s+)(.+)`
b. Shipto: `Sh[lit1I|]pto:(?:\s+\d+\s+)(.+)`

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you did not actually present the programming language in question, so I am going to show a possible solution in `PHP`:

```
<?php
$string = 'Soldto:                              Shipto:                                 Billto:                                 
00011222                                00017872                                10221060                                
COSTCO CO INC. - GLOBAL EDI             COSTCO LANGLEY DEPOT                    COSTCO CO/LANGLEY                       ';
$regex = '~               # delimiter
            ^Soldto:      # look for "Soldto:" at the beginning of the string
            (?:.*\R){2}   # match everything up to the end + newline (2 times)
            (?<poi>.*)    # capture the whole third row into the group "poi"
        ~x';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $columns = preg_split('~\s{2,}~', $match["poi"]);
    # the idea here is to watch out for at least 2 consecutive spaces
    # and use this as delimiter

    print_r($columns);
    /* output
    Array
    (
        [0] => COSTCO CO INC. - GLOBAL EDI
        [1] => COSTCO LANGLEY DEPOT
        [2] => COSTCO CO/LANGLEY
        [3] => 
    )
    */
}
?>
```

This can obviously adjusted to suit your needs, but your data can be accessed in the `$columns` array now.

To only get the string from the first column (`COSTCO CO INC. - GLOBAL EDI`), you could use the following regex:

```
^Soldto:(?:.*\R){2}\K((?:(?!\s{2}).)+)
```

See a [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/gG8uD4/1).

Comment: Thanks for your help. The programming language is C#. I will try to work with your suggestion. Point of order: This regex pulls the first entry ("COSTCO CO INC. - GLOBAL EDI".)     Billto:\s*\d+\s*\d+\s+\d+\s+(.{32})

Comment: Nice, While you were posting that I found a way based on the top entry in the third column. This one gets the second entry on the third line: Billto:\s*\d+\s*\d+\s*\d+\s*(?:.{32})\s*(.{32})

Comment: I like your regex. It works for the first column. So, how do I isolate the second entry on the third line?

Comment: I am using this to capture it as a group, but I do not know how to make the entire first result non-capturing.  `^Soldto:(?:.*\R){2}\K((?:(?!\s{2}).)+)\K\s*\K((?:(?!\s{2}).)+)` See your edited [demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/gG8uD4/1)